# OAuth2 and Single Page App - ensure client is mine

Tags: node.js, angularjs, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

In a single page app (in my case AngularJS fetched from static at a node.js + express + oauth2orize) what assures me that my client is actually... well my client? (I'm referring to Implicit Grants)

Am I missing something in that some malicious client could simply allow the user to sign in, then request a token with my client ID? Is there a way to sign my client before it is sent? Like a spec I missed out on?

The idea is that my service is a full out OAuth2 provider, but I want to provide a single page app via implicit grant to something like a Dashboard for the user to create and edit info. But I just want to be sure it's my client, the one they got from me.

If you know of specs or methods of assuring this, I'd like to see those docs. My guess right now is to generate a unique cert every time the client is requested (initial or refresh) and have that sent back in session on login.

Answer (score 0):

If your client is using client flow, then no. All you can do is obfuscate your code and client id. If you are really concerned, then perhaps use the server flow. So your client will ask your server for the token and your server can take whatever precautions you see fit. Same Origin Policy will then provide you with some protection that the client code came from your site.